# Views filtering by two values from same field and comparing with another time field

Tags: views, 9

I have a customer which works with buses and passenger transportation.Now he would like that all routes would be visible on a site and guests could filter routes by source and destination points.
Routes examples:

Route A-E
StopA 08:10
StopB 08:20
StopC 08:30
StopD 08:40
StopE 08:50

Route E-A
StopE 09:00
StopD 09:10
StopC 09:20
StopB 09:30
StopA 09:40

Now client wants Search fields Source and Destination and for example if Source has value StopB and Destination has value StopC than user should only see Route A-E

How I'm doing this:

Firstly I created a new paragraph and added two fields in it: stop(text field) and time (time field)
[image]

Then I Created a content type Routes and added newly created paragraph
[image]

When I'm creating a new Content of Routes I can add as many stops with time as I like.
[image]

I created a view:
[image]

It shows all data as expected
[image]

I added Relationship field_stops: Paragraph
After that data multiplied 5 times same amount as routes in Content. Why is that?

Then I was able to add Filter Criteria field_stops: Paragraph

Now if I type StopB in filter field it filters both routes: Route A-E and Route E-A and it's normal because both of them has StopB value

[image]

Now I need ideas how can I add another filter field and search for both values in Routes.
And how to implement source and destination route? Can it use time field?

I hope I'm clear with my question

Comment: Well its combine  filter   check this  hope it helps you https://befused.com/drupal/views-combined-filter/

Comment: Thanks for a hint. I checked the link but it says: In order to use this, the view format needs to be set to show fields. It doesn’t work if you want to display rendered entities as there are no fields to combine. And Paragraph is Rendered entity so I can't select these fields.